# Prevent form to repost on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given is a form that is followed by a confirmation page where you have to confirm you entered data of previous form. Now if the user refreshes this recapitulation page, the data form the previous form reposts. Is there a way to prevent that in JavaScript?

I know its not a ideal solution, it should happen on the server side. But i have no choice in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't prevent the user from reposting using javascript. This should be done server side using the [redirect after post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

---

#### UPDATE

A possible but not robust solution is to simulate the redirect from javascript using `window.location.href`.

Comment: i know. But this is not an option here :( but +1 for the link i gonna send to the dev that is "not avalible" :/

Comment: Then neither is what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am afraid that's the only option. Also users might have javascript disabled. Using javascript you could probably redirect using `window.location.href` but once again this is not a robust solution.

Comment: i know its not robust. Really. For now i just gonna redirect the user on window.location.href. Once i can contact the dev i gonna send him your link. Could you just edit your answer, and add the "unrobust" js solution. So i can confirm your answer?

Comment: Voted up for the link ;-)

Answer (score 24):

You CAN do this in JavaScript using `history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.href);` to clear the post data.  I've tested this on an MVC related table editor (that I created myself) that posts to the same url and it works great.

Comment: This answer deserves to be accepted and rated up. It worked fine for me.