# Avoid form resubmission if page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am submitting a form, contains username and password, if I have entered incorrect username and password it gives an error message "Invalid username or password".
Then if I am refreshing page just using browsers reload button or using f5,it asks to resubmit a form,if I pressed on continue it is again showing same error message,that means it is taking my previous details as it is.

How to avoid this?

I want to hide that error message if I refresh my page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent form to repost on refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013914/prevent-form-to-repost-on-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function submitCheck(){  
    if(condition==true)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

When your condition fails return false.
it will stop form from submitting.